# Algorithm cross-referencing problem

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, algorithms

I have multiple algorithms and I have changed counter in between. When I am cross-referencing a later algorithm, it gets linked to the original sequence instead of the actual algorithm. For example, suppose I have this code,

```
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
...
\begin(algorithm)
   \caption{\label{algo1}}
\end{algorithm}
\setcounter{algocf}{0}
\begin(algorithm)
   \caption{\label{algo2}}
\end{algorithm}
...
\end{document}
```

When I am trying to reference Algorithm 2 (`\ref{algo2}`), then the hyperlink generated in the pdf jumps to  `algo1` instead of `algo2`.

Any ideas, why??

How do I update the counter so that this problem does not arise?? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this approach you should notice the following in your `.log`:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `algo1' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.

[1

{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}pdfTeX warning (e
xt4): destination with the same identifier (name{algocf.1}) has been already us
ed, duplicate ignored
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...
l.19 \end{document}
```

This results from [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) needing a unique identifier to jump to, yet you've made the identifier the same due to resetting (or stepping back) the `algocf` counter (the [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) counter identifying the algorithm).

One possible reason for this is because you want to split an algorithm across multiple pages yet still number them the same. Or, possibly, provide an updated version (improvement, maybe) of the previous algorithm.

To achieve this properly, you need to load `hyperref` with the `hypertexnames=false` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

See Algorithm~\ref{alg:algo1} and~\ref{alg:algo2}. There is also Algorithm~\ref{alg:algo3}.

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{First algorithm}
  \label{alg:algo1}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \setcounter{algocf}{0}% Reset algorithm counter (algocf)
  \caption{Second algorithm}
  \label{alg:algo2}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Third algorithm}
  \label{alg:algo3}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```